# Django: reference model fields from another model

Tags: django, model, field

I have two models. What i need is to reference the *name* and the *email* field from the `Users model` to the `Customer model` fields. Is the following way correct?

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

```
from users.models import Users

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    name = models.OneToOneField(
        Users.name, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    email = models.OneToOneField(
        Users.email, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

That's all. Then you can do for example

```
Customer.objects.get(pk=1).user.name
```